# JSF 1.2 Tomcat redeployment error

Tags: jsf, tomcat, mojarra

I'm using JSF 1.2 with Spring on Tomcat 6.0.18. I am able to successfully deploy my application on Tomcat, but when undeploying following error occurs:

```
INFO  [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] Undeploying context [/myapp]
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/myapp]] Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/FacesException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1847)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1217)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.FacesException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    ... 29 more
```

I am using Mojarra implementation of JSF, version 1.2_15. Here is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app>
        <display-name>my App</display-name>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
            <param-value>server</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>


        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
</web-app>
```

If someone had similar problem, I would really appreciate a help regarding this issue. Thanx!

[Edit]
After downgrading from JSF 1.2_15 to JSF 1.2_03-b09, deployment/undeployment seem to work fine, but I've still getting warning messages (i.e. I was getting the same messages also with 1.2_15, just before error messages). Here is the extract from log:

Undeployment:

```
INFO  [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] Undeploying context [/myapp]
INFO  [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] Undeploying context [/myapp]
WARN  [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] Error while removing context [/myapp]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1046)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1214)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2011-03-01 10:05:16,906 WARN  [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] Error during context [/myapp] destroy
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1052)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1214)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

And just after that, when I'm executing deployment, here is the log:

```
INFO  [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] Deploying web application archive myapp.war
INFO  [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load java.lang.Object.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1273)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ConverterPropertyEditorFactory$DisposableClassLoader.loadClass(ConverterPropertyEditorFactory.java:446)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at java.beans.PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(PropertyEditorManager.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addPropertyEditorIfNecessary(ApplicationImpl.java:697)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:668)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:804)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:544)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:830)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1471)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:645)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:640)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I've google a bit, and it seems it's errors are caused due to Tomcat version. Unfortunately, I'm not able to switch to newer version. Could someone advise me if it's possible to solve this errors Tomcat 6.0.18, that I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sign of classpath pollution.

Ensure that you do not have duplicated JSF libraries anywhere else in the classpath, such as in `JRE/lib` and `JRE/lib/ext` folders (where `JRE` is the installation folder of your Java SE Runtime Environment), or in `Tomcat/lib` folder (where `Tomcat` is the installation folder of your Tomcat).

Comment: I haven't been able to find any duplicated JSF libraries on my classpath. So, I've decided to try to downgrade from JSF 1.2_15 to 1.2_03-b09. After this, deployment/undeployment seems to be executed ok, although I'm still getting warning messages. I've updated my question, with the new tomcat log.

Comment: Then this smells more like that your Tomcat is messed up. Is it a fresh new and untouched installation?

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is probably the matter. It is not fresh new, it was provided by a client, there are some custom libraries in tomcat lib folder, which are probably causing these issues. I do not believe that I will have a freedom to change/remove this libs in Prod environment...Anyway, thanx for your help!